# How can I monitor multiple Statistics from different classes in Gem5 at the same time dynamiclly?

Tags: gem5

Which class in Gem5 has access to all the Stats from different objects? 
Do the statistics of each object being returned to specific class continuously or these stats are collected just at the end of the simulation?

For example `servicedByWrQ` is a Scalar stat defined in the `dram_ctrl.hh`. On the other hand `condPredicted` is another Scalar stat which is defined in the `bpred_unit.hh`. How can I monitor these two statistics at the same time during the simulation not through the output file in Gem5?

My ultimate goal is to change the behavior other hardware units during the simulations such as branch prediction or cache replacement policy, etc. based on those statistics.

Comment: I haven't touched threads much, so I don't know the answer. But I would also explain what is your end goal in more detail: what do you want to do with those stats? Will they be used to somehow affect the behavior some hardware component in the simulation itself?